# Hyperledger Channel Creation

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am new to hyperledger and I want to understand more on channel. I am working on POC, where I need to have private transaction between 2 parties,so I want to understand how should i configure my network.

- Should I have different chaincode for each channel or one chaincode can be used across 2 channels.
- It is multi user application and user coming across and can do transaction on any channel, how should the identity be configured. Should we have intermediate user or identity to communicate or is it good to use application user identity can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating a network comprised many organizations, but want to design a means of preserving confidentiality of a transaction between two organizations A and B, then you would create a channel that has org A and B as participants, and deploy the chaincode(s) to the endorsing peer nodes for each org.

As for end-user identity, that would typically be designed such that the end-users were members of one or the other org, and their authentication and authorization would be somehow managed by each org. For instance, let's say that the end users are employees of org A and org B, then you could use your corporate LDAP as a means of authenticating and authorizing them to perform certain transactions.

Alternately, if they are customers of A and B, then whatever user authentication and authorization you have for managing end users could be used. Whatever authentication is used, the MSP (membership services provider) for each org would need to be adapted to support the means used when issuing identity certificates.

The [Hyperledger Fabric CA Users Guide](http://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) has specifics.

Comment: Thank You Chris ! Gives me idea how to do it. Also is there a sample client application you are aware, which use the API to create channels and user identities.

Comment: can fabric-ca connect to any nosql db, for authentication, if we dont have LDAP for authorization. Or how does that architecture works.

Comment: You need to implement the msp interface, but yeah, you could do that.